# How to find max value in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I have to complete the method **maxElem(Node node)** in such a way that the method **maxElem()** returns the maximum value contained in a binary tree.

How can I do that? I do not know how to do that..

```
public class BinaryTree {

    protected class Node {
        protected Integer element;
        protected Node left;
        protected Node right;

        Node(int element) {
            this.element = element;
            left = right = null;
        }

        Node(int element, Node left, Node right) {
            this.element = element;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

    } //end Node class

    public class NodeReference {
        private Node node;

        private NodeReference(Node node) {
            this.node = node;
        }

        public int getElement() {
            return node.element;
        }

        public void setElement(int e) {
            node.element = e;
        }
    }

    protected Node root;

    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    private class BoolNode {

        boolean found; 
        Node node;

        BoolNode(boolean found, Node node) {
            this.found = found;
            this.node = node;
        }
    }

    public int maxElem() {
        if(root == null) 
            throw new IllegalStateException("Empty tree.");
        return maxElem(root);
    }


    private static int max3(int x, int y, int z) {
        return max(x, max(y, z));
    }

    private int maxElem(Node node) {
        //...
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
private int maxElem(Node node) {
    int max = node.element;
    if(node.left != null) {
        max = Math.max(max, maxElem(node.left));
    }
    if(node.right != null) {
        max = Math.max(max, maxElem(node.right));
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Since this looks like a homework, I think it would be more appropriate to explain the principle of the recursive walk through the tree than just giving him the code.

Answer (score 1):

**1**)Using **Recursion**:

**Note**:You need the add `getElement()`, `getRight()`, `getLeft()` methods in your *Node* class so that the below code could work.

```
public int findMaxInTree(Node root) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;     //set a default max value
        if (root == null)
            return max;                 //if root is null
        else {
            int left_max = findMaxInTree(root.getLeft());           //get left side max
            int right_max = findMaxInTree(root.getRight());         //get right side max
            if (left_max > right_max)                               //if left>right
                max = left_max;                                     //set max=left
            else
                max=right_max;                                      //else set max=right

            if (root.getElement() > max)                           //if root is greater than max of left or right
                max = root.getElement();                              //set max=root

        }
        return max;                                                //return max
    }
```

**2**)You can use the *concept* of **Breadth First Traversal** to find the max.

```
public void findMax(Node root) {
            if (root == null)
                System.out.println("empty tree");
            else {
                Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();  //make a queue
                Node max = root;                              //suppose max is root
                queue.add(root);                              //add root to queue
                while (queue.size() != 0) {                  //while size of queue is not empty  
                    Node temp = queue.remove();              //remove an item from queue
                    if (temp.getElement() > max.getElement())    //if removed item is greater than max
                        max = temp;                             //set new max
                    if (temp.getLeft() != null)                                  
                        queue.add(temp.getLeft());             //traverse left
                    if (temp.getRight() != null)
                        queue.add(temp.getRight());            //traverse right
                }
                System.out.println(max.getElement());       //in the end ,print the max
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could get the maximum value of a tree.

```java
public static int maxElem(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    int max = Math.max(maxElem(node.left), maxElem(node.right));
    return max > node.element ? max : node.element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static void maxElement(Node node, int max){
            static int MaxTemp;
            if(node==null)
                return;
            if(node.getData()>min)
                MaxTemp=node.getData();
            if(node.getLeft()!=null && node.getLeft().getData()>max)
                MaxTemp=node.getLeft().getData();
            if(node.getRight()!=null && node.getRight().getData()>max)
                MaxTemp=node.getRight().getData();
            maxElement(node.getLeft(), MaxTemp);
            maxElement(node.getRight(), MaxTemp);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int maxInTree(BinTreeNode<int> t)
    {
        int max = t.GetInfo();
        if (t != null)
        {
            if (t.GetLeft() != null)
                max = Math.Max(max, maxInTree(t.GetLeft()));
            if (t.GetRight() != null)
                max = Math.Max(max, maxInTree(t.GetRight()));
        }
        return max;
    }
```